# registering a dll, in visual foxpro 7, windows 7

Tags: dll, visual-foxpro

i have an application written in VFP 7, somewhere in the application i call a function in a dll using the following :

```
declare long FunctionName in DLL_NAME.dll string@, string@
.
.
.
RETURN FunctionName( StringParam1, StringParam2)
```

calling this function generates an error :

```
The following error has occurred:
Message: Cannot load 32-bit DLL d:\folder\DLL_NAME.dll.
```

i tried registering the dll using the 32/64 bit regsvr...no luck !

Info that could help identify the problem :
the dll file is not local, it is in a folder in a network mapped drive.

thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is running on Win 7 32 bits

Comment: Visual FoxPro 7 does not support a 64-bit operating system.  "Message: Cannot load 32-bit DLL d:\folder\DLL_NAME.dll." tells me you are trying to load a 32-bit DLL within a program compiled as a x64 process.  Futhermore....A 32-bit operating system DOES NOT have a 64-bit version of the regsvr process.  I suggest using Visual FoxPro 9 SP2 to see if you have better results.  VP7 was release 10 years ago.

Comment: Furthermore it sounds like the user account does not have the require priviliages require to read of the network.  Try making the file local...

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that VFP9SP2 or VFP7 support x64 operating systems.  Based on the fact you are using a 64-bit operating system based on a statement you made in your question means should look at other choices.

Comment: ok thanks, will do more research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from VFP not supporting anything 64-bit, I would look at the fact you are trying to load a dll across the network.

Eliminate that as a possible issue and copy it LOCALLY and load it from that...

Try to eliminate everything ELSE, including your VFP application.  I would start directly from the VFP command window and do nothing but have a simple .prg file.  In it, put nothing but the declaration and reference a LOCAL copy of the dll file.  Set the values for your parameters, and then call the function.

If that doesn't work, then it doesn't matter WHERE in the application its being called... you've just eliminated that whole set of conditions and environment.

Its almost like support I offer to clients sometimes when trying to do something in our app that requests data from the internet.  I have them manually go to their browser and put in whatever URL our app would be trying to go to.  If they can't get to it from the browser, its something from their firewall, IP blocking, or other... it has nothing to do with our app.  You might be running into a similar situation.  Leave out all other elements and just get the few to absolutely test the problem isolated to itself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i will follow those steps, hopefully it is the network issue and not the 64 bit incompatibility!

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the issue is likely that the dlls are located on a shared network. I have solved this problem in the past by copying the files to the local machine(s).

However, according to this article (link below), you *can* allow a FoxPro app (or any .exe for that matter) to use dll's from a networked drive if you add a special config file that tells the .Net framework that it's okay to access networked dlls for a certain app.

Here is the link: http://www.west-wind.com/webconnection/docs/index.htm?page=_36e0qlogr.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link. FYI the application is running on XP client and loading the dll remotely and successfully from the same place. i think it is a compatibility issue with Windows 7 (dll not compatible with 64-bit maybe ?). I'm still searching, and will post the answer, once this mysterious problem solved.